# Code Golf Birthday Cake

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

Your task is to print this exact text:

```
     | | | | | |
    &***********&
    | Code Golf |
   | e---------f |
  | d___________l |
 | o-------------o |
| C_______________G |
 ###Dennis$Dennis###
#####################
```

## Rules

- Trailing or leading newline is allowed
- [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

Comment: The numbers being weird like that doesn't make sense and makes this challenge even less interesting than it is. I would recommend moving the candles inwards by one so that there are only 5 and then you can do 0 2 4 6 8 or 1 3 5 7 9

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 71 bytes

```
\|6*Ṅ`&`×6*+∞`¬꘍ »₆`:⌈Rvf÷4ɾd7+‛-_f4Ẏ*$++J‛ |Ḃ∇++÷`###%$`∞‛ṫ¹%\#21*WøĊ⁋
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJcXHw2KuG5hGAmYMOXNior4oieYMKs6piNIMK74oKGYDrijIhSdmbDtzTJvmQ3K+KAmy1fZjThuo4qJCsrSuKAmyB84biC4oiHKyvDt2AjIyMlJGDiiJ7igJvhuavCuSVcXCMyMSpXw7jEiuKBiyIsIiIsIiJd)

```
=== Top bit ===
\|6*Ṅ`&`×6*+∞
\|6*          # Six |
    Ṅ         # Join by spaces
     `&`   +  # Append to an &
        ×6*   # six asterisks
            ∞ # Palindromise that

=========== Code Golf bit ===========
`¬꘍ »₆`:                              # Compressed string `Code Golf`, two copies
        ⌈R                            # Split on spaces and reverse each word
          vf÷                         # Make each a char list and push each
             4ɾ                       # 1...4
               d7+                    # Double + 7 -> 9, 11, 13, 15
                  ‛-_f4Ẏ              # Extend `-_` into length 4 and turn into char list
                        *             # Repeat characters by numbers
                         $++          # Join the `Code Golf` bit by those
                            J         # Append `Code Golf`
                             ‛ |Ḃ     # Push ` |` and `| `
                                 ∇++  # Prepend `| ` and append ` |` to each
                                    ÷ # Push each value to the stack.

=== Final bit ===
`###%$`               # Literal string `###%$`
       ∞              # Palindromised
        ‛ṫ¹%          # Format (replace % by) "Dennis"
            \#21*     # 21 #
                 WøĊ⁋ # Output the stack, centred and joined on newlines.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 69 bytes

```
× |³⸿×*⁶&⸿Ｅ⁵⁺×§_-ι⁺⁵ι |Ｅ²×#⁺χι‖Ｏ←Ｍ±⁶±²…Dennis$¹³↗↖Golf←floG edo↙CedoC
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9LC8IwEITv/ooQRRKp4AM91JNUEMEXojdBSt3aQExKG6uC/z1ua9B6y858M5uNkjCLdCit3WZCGbYXV8gZJS/qkSHnk8ZHpseMfgfHdBAZ15B2nVmFKRt5ZCtvueOnZqHO8GD01MWg4M4clW8cypWc/@UHHnGrmtTR/V6Fl9wOYgmR2RSQSYT9JcQG5ZUugK3hEhpgY@x1z8GvOnhGEoJEp4zOQCmRt7C9Xx1bhf1DuhOXxHwDKJTl@Me5lvHvRt@psdRzAmddc2b6rpwboBOgZa3tFvIN) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Outputs the right half of the cake body, reflects it, then adds in the lettering.

```
× |³⸿
```

Handle the candles.

```
×*⁶&⸿
```

Handle the icing.

```
Ｅ⁵⁺×§_-ι⁺⁵ι |
```

Draw the bulk of the cake.

```
Ｅ²×#⁺χι
```

Draw the base of the cake.

```
‖Ｏ←
```

Reflect to complete the cake body.

```
Ｍ±⁶±²…Dennis$¹³↗
```

Cyclically extend the string `Dennis$` to 13 characters and output it in the appropriate position.

```
↖Golf←floG edo↙CedoC
```

Add the two copies of `Code` and `Golf`.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 145 bytes

```javascript
_=>` 5|@@@@@
 4&*11&
 4| Code Golf@
 3| e-9f@
 @ d_11l@
@ o-13o@
| C_15G@
 #3Dennis$Dennis#3
#21`.replace(/@|.(\d+)/g,([c],n)=>c.repeat(n)||' |')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpNCoMwGET3OcUHFk1af4ipiy6UQAseoi0aYhRLSESlq9w9jXQ2b5g3H/EVm1znZc@MHZQfa9/VTQ@V40cQXOMzpXGgg3s4QGv1GGbmQGW3o3EYOko1RxxsRpnlKDw7WrXBReyhjJm30x8RQ1FJ@3xVixZS4YK7HL@GCymmFD/lOzWkbuShldixIc4l4BLipTWb1SrXdsIjJsT/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 114 bytes

```
    6$*¦¶    &11$**&¶   ¦ Code Golf¦¶  ¦ e9$*-f¦¶ ¦ d11$*_l¦¶¦ o13$*-o¦¶| C15$*_G¦¶ ###D$D###¶21$*#
¦
 |
D
Dennis
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fSwEIzFS0Di07tA3EVDM0VNHSUgNzDi1TcM5PSVVwz89Jg8gDRVItVbR0IVwgLwWkPD4HxAXy8g2NgZL5IF6NgrOhKVDKHaxSWVnZRcUFSB7aZgTUoMx1aBmXQg2XC5dLal5eZvH//wA) Explanation:

```
    6$*¦¶    &11$**&¶   ¦ Code Golf¦¶  ¦ e9$*-f¦¶ ¦ d11$*_l¦¶¦ o13$*-o¦¶| C15$*_G¦¶ ###D$D###¶21$*#
```

Insert most of the cake using run-length encoding.

```
¦
 |
D
Dennis
```

Make a couple of substitutions that save a few bytes. (In particular, the `¦` substitution allows me to write `6$*¦` to mean  `| | | | | |`.)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-p0513`, 119 bytes

Pretty much just RLE, nothing too exciting.

```perl
s''4 6P
4 &11*&
3 P Code GolfP
  P e9-fP
 P d11_lP
P o13-oP
| C15_GP
 3#Dennis$Dennis3#
21#';s/\d+(.)/$1x$&/ge;s/P/ |/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYnNCgIhFEb3PsWFEe0Hs5tjEC0nmO19gGA22jAgKtmixTx7ZrT6zjlf9s9gay1S9nAm1oNA3AlmgGBIzsOYwoMYNPUX9SMChzgFYgQJjUrEVhjQTmP7THfzMS6F/8d07ISdvBZ9d/vNYas5vrnQs2@FNKx6rvWT8mtJsVSVjxbNFw)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 77 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
„| 11∍'*11×'&.ø”|ƒËŠˆ |”©Âá4.£v'|y„-_NèN·9+×y®á2ä`‡««‚Ć}”¼´$”13∍…###.ø¬21×».c
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcO8GgVDw0cdvepahoaHp6ur6R3e8ahhbs2xSYe7jy443aZQA@QdWnm46fBCE71Di8vUayqBenTj/Q6v8Du03VL78PTKQ@sOLzQ6vCThUcPCQ6sPrX7UMOtIWy1I155DW1SAtKEx0PhHDcuUlZWBhh9aYwS059BuveT//wE)

**Explanation:**

```python
„|               # Push string "| "
   11∍           # Extend it to size 11: "| | | | | |"
'*              '# Push character "*"
  11×            # Repeat it 11 times: "***********"
     '&.ø       '# Surround it with leading/trailing "&": "&***********&"
”|ƒËŠˆ |”        # Push dictionary string "| Code Golf |"
         ©       # Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
Â                # Bifurcate it (short for Duplicate & Reverse copy):
                 # "| floG edoC |"
 á               # Only leave the letters: "floGedoC"
  4.£            # Only leave the last 4 characters: "edoC"
     v           # Foreach `y` over these characters:
      '|        '#  Push character "|"
      y          #  Push character `y`
      „-_        #  Push string "-|"
         Nè      #  Index (0-based modular) the map-index into this string
           N·    #  Push double the map-index
             9+  #  Add 9
               × #  Repeat the character that many times
      y          #  Push the character again
       ®         #  Push "| Code Golf |" from variable `®`
        á        #  Only leave its letters: "CodeGolf"
         2ä      #  Split it into two equal-sized parts: ["Code","Gold"]
           `     #  Pop and push both separated to the stack
            ‡    #  Transliterate
      ««         #  Append the top three strings together
      ‚          #  Pair it with the "|"
       Ć         #  Enclose; append its own head (the "|")
     }           # Close the foreach
”¼´$”            # Push dictionary string "Dennis$"
     13∍         # Extend it to size 13: "Dennis$Dennis"
        …###.ø   # Surround it with leading/trailing "###":
                 # "###Dennis$Dennis###"
¬                # Push the first character (without popping): "#"
 21×             # Repeat it 21 times: "###################"
»                # Join each list on the stack by spaces,
                 # and then all strings on the stack by newlines
 .c              # Centralize it, adding leading spaces where necessary
                 # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `”|ƒËŠˆ |”` is `"| Code Golf |"` and `”¼´$”` is `"Dennis$"`.